# How do I change the keyboard layout to a non-standard one on a Live (USB) session?

Tags: live-usb, keyboard-layout, live-environment

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 in a Live (USB) session. My physical keyboard layout is called Bépo, it is the French language Dvorak method-based layout.
I would like to change my input layout to this too.

To do this, I tried booting in a French spoken session, then open the Keyboard Layout preferences app. Normally, to add a layout, you should click on the + sign and select your layout. However the list that appears is very short and does not contain what I want. On the contrary, on a persistent non-live installation, the choice of Bépo is present. This is also the case during an installation of Ubuntu.

So I do I change the keyboard layout of my live session to the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to own test on a Live USB session of Ubuntu 13.10, it seems to now be possible to change the keyboard layout to a non-standard one.

This is probably due to the introduction of a new keyboard indicator (see http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/ubuntu-1310-available-for-download.html for instance).